# How to get a sheet name in an ODS file?

Tags: python, ods, pyexcel

I saw that there are two libraries I can use: `pyexcel_ods3` and `pyexcel_ods`.
I tried to use

```
pyexcel_ods.Sheet("file.ods")
```

and

```
pyexcel_ods.get_book(file_name="file.ods")
```

but I got these errors:

```
AttributeError: module 'pyexcel_ods' has no attribute 'Sheet'

AttributeError: module 'pyexcel_ods' has no attribute 'get_book'
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably made a mistake installing.

Check you have both `pyexcel` and `pyexcel-ods`:

```
pip install pyexcel pyexcel-ods
```

Try the following code:

```
from pyexcel import get_book

sheet = get_book(file_name="file_example_ODS_10.ods")
print(sheet)
```

(you can get a valid example file here https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-documents-download/sample-ods-download/)

To get names:

```
from pyexcel import get_book

sheet = get_book(file_name="file_example_ODS_10.ods")
print(sheet.sheet_names())
```

Result:

```
['Sheet1']
```

Note that, in your example, you were trying to call `get_book` and `Sheet` directly on the `pyexcel_ods` module, while I only import `pyexcel` (and have the ods module installed) and that just works, pyexcel finds the module automatically when opening a .ods file.

Comment: No... that's not the case.
I'm trying to get the name of the sheet, like "Sheet1"

Comment: If you get the two libraries I mention above, download the example file and try the code, you'll get exactly what you asked.

Comment: The problem was: I was not using .sheet_names() method . Thank you!